# Selenium and BeautifulSoup not finding all elements on this webpage

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new to web scraping I wanted to scrape data regarding COVID-19 from worldometer.com.
But selenium and BeautifulSoup find only 7 of the latest tags.
This is the code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 driver=webdriver.Firefox()

 driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/india/')

 rise = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("news_li")

 num_days = len(rise) print(len(rise)) print for i in range(num_days):
     print(rise[i].text)
```

This is the code for beautifulsoup:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup from urllib.request import Request,
 urlopen url="https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/india/"
 req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

 web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

 webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

 bsobj=BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser') for k in
 bsobj.findAll("li",{"class":"news_li"}):
     print(k.find("strong").next_sibling.next_sibling.get_text())

 for b in bsobj.findAll("button",{"class":"btn btn-light date-btn"}):
     print(b['data-date'])
```

This is the output for selenium:

> 7
>   1,125 new cases and 12 new deaths in India [source]

This is the output for beautiful soup:

> 2,006 new deaths 395 new deaths 321 new deaths 309 new deaths 389 new
>   deaths 2020-06-17 2020-06-16 2020-06-15 2020-06-14 2020-06-13
>   2020-06-12

Comment: the older updates only appear on the page and in the DOM after you've clicked the "view more news" button. So you would need to use selenium to click the button until all older days have appeared. Then you can search for all li elements with "news_li" as a class.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. Could you tell me how to do that

Comment: you can check out [this ](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/) to find out how to click a button. I think you probably need to write a loop that finds and clicks the button untill the button disappears, when there are no more older updates.